# PlayFramework - Page Sort by last Entry of OneToMany Relationship

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I've got the following structure:

```
public class ConversationModel extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="conversation", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<EventModel> events;

}
```

and

```
public abstract class EventModel extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public Date time;

}
```

Now when I fetch a page from Conversation Model, I want to order them by the latest entry of EventModel in the array events.

I tried something like:

```
            return find.where().disjunction()
                .add(Expr.ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%"))
                ...
                .orderBy("events.time desc, " + sortBy + " " + order)
                .findPagedList(page, pageSize);
```

But this somehow returns an entry of ConversationModel in the paged list for each event. (e.g. 3 times the same conversation if it has 3 events)
If I omit "events desc" in the orderBy query, I get the desired result, but not sorted correctly.

I also tried setting `.setDistinct(true)` in the query, but that returns "Invalid SQL Syntax".

How can I sort all my conversations to their latest event entry?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

I've setup a sample project, which shows the problem:

https://github.com/dominik-ziegler/play-page-sort

On first start the application prints the conversations to the console:

```
[debug] - application - Conversation: First Conversation; ID1
[debug] - application - Conversation Last Message: Tue Jan 12 23:03:55 CET 2016
[debug] - application - ----------
[debug] - application - ----------
[debug] - application - Conversation: Second Conversation; ID2
[debug] - application - Conversation Last Message: Tue Jan 12 23:03:55 CET 2016
[debug] - application - ----------
[debug] - application - ----------
[debug] - application - Conversation: Third Conversation; ID3
[debug] - application - Conversation Last Message: Tue Jan 12 23:03:55 CET 2016
[debug] - application - ----------
```

But according to the insert date the order should be:

1. Second Conversation
2. Third Conversation
3. First Conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ConversationModel` you can annotate the field with `@javax.persistence.OrderBy`, i.e.:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="conversation", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("time DESC")
public List<EventModel> events;
```

It will do what you need - will sort events as you wish without touching the main sorting (so you can add other sort for conversations in your find query).

**Edit:** To achieve what you want you will need to perform a query with
 `GROUP BY conversation.id` and `ORDER BY event.id`:

(*MySQL pseudo code*):

```
SELECT c.id c0, e.id FROM conversation c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN event e ON c.id = e.conversation_id 
    WHERE lower(c.name) LIKE '%foo%'
    GROUP BY c.id
    ORDER BY e.id DESC;
```

Unfortunately bare Finder won't let you to do this, but you may construct your `PagedList` with own `WHERE` with added grouping like:

```
PagedList<ConversationModel> convsPage = Ebean
     .createQuery(
         ConversationModel.class, 
         "WHERE lower(name) like :search GROUP BY id"
     )
     .setParameter("search","%"+filter+"%")
     .order("events.id DESC")
     .findPagedList(page, pageSize);
```

Comment: Check the pull request, also clean the comments under this post ;) if commit is what you need let me know I'll change the answer

Comment: You sir are an absolute genius! Thank you!